# how to initialize boost::edge_weight_t type on VS C++

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2015

The following code generate this warning when it is compiled with VS C++ This warning causes an exec error.

```
     boost::edge_weight_t EdgeWeightPropType;
```

The warning is:

```
     warning C4700 uninitialized local variable EdgeWeightPropType
```

Note: the edge_weight_t is defined as follow:

```
  enum edge_weight_t{ edge_weight };
    template <> struct property_kind<edge_weight_t> {
     typedef edge_property_tag type;
  };
```

How can I avoid this warning or initialise this variable?

Comment: Try to have a look at this [page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/graph/doc/using_adjacency_list.html)

Comment: But I couldn't know how initialise this variable.

Comment: I think you should define something like `typedef property<edge_weight_t, float> EdgeProperty;` as shown in the boost documentation.

Comment: This definition is not allowed. This variable is called as follow:  ||||||||||  boost::add_edge(nCurrentIndx2, (*Ei).m_target, get( EdgeWeightPropType, G, (*Ei)), G); |||||||||||| IfI use typedef property<edge_weight_t, float> EdgeProperty; to define it I got compilation error. I just need to know How it can be initialized. This bug is produced only with windows not with Linux

Answer (score 0):

EdgeWeightPropType can be initialized as follow:

```
 boost::edge_weight_t  EdgeWeightPropType = boost::edge_weight;
```